# Connection refused with Go + Postgres on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, go

I am trying to connect to Heroku's Postgres using a Go. All is working fine locally.

The error I am receiving on Heroku is `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connection refused`.

I've confirmed my ability to connect to the database via psql on heroku's command line, and have confirmed that the database url config is correct. The code is clear enough, so I wonder if there is a lower-level problem.

The code is straightforward enough:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/coopernurse/gorp"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "os"
)

func openDb() *sql.DB {
    connection := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connection)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    return db
}
```

...and am importing github.com/lib/pq. Go version is 1.1.2.

Answer (score 11):

Heroku + Go is pretty particular about the connection strings. The URL-style doesn't seem to allow specification of sslmode=require, which Heroku [insists upon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress).

The modified version uses pq to parse the URL into a traditional Postgres connection string, and appends the parameter:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
    "os"
)

func openDb() *sql.DB {
    url := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")
    connection, _ := pq.ParseURL(url)
    connection += " sslmode=require"

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connection)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    return db
}
```

Comment: Strange... I've never had to mess with `sslmode=require`, and I've done something very similar (also using `lib/pq`). Also, it's bad practice to include DB connection details in your code. Heroku allows you to set environment variables, which your code can access using `os.Getenv()`. Good luck! :)